# How to detect with a script, when marker is found using aframe-ar.js?

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I tried without success this suggested script, how can I make it work?

```
if(document.querySelector("a-marker").object3D.visible == true) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom component checking the visibility on tick:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('markerhandler', {
   tick:function() {
      if(document.querySelector("a-marker").object3D.visible == true) {
      // MARKER IS PRESENT
      } else {
      // MARKER IS HIDDEN
      }
   }
});
```

You can also use a [throttled tick](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/utils.html#aframe-utils-throttletick-function-t-dt-minimuminterval-optionalcontext), to make a 100 - 500 ms interval for the tick.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to hide a "spinnerScanning" element but still unsuccessful, I'm adding: document.getElementById('spinnerScanning').style.visibility = 'hidden'; What am I doing wrong in this script? AFRAME.registerComponent('markerhandler' { tick:function() { if(document.querySelector("a-marker").object3D.visible == true) { document.getElementById('area').style.visibility = 'hidden'; } else { document.getElementById('area').style.visibility = 'visible';  } } });

Comment: the `#area` is an a-frame entity ?

Comment: No is a <div class="area" >..content..</div>

Comment: @MiguelNunes then i'm pretty sure Your div is showing up below the aframe canvas. Try setting the z-index value, so it will be on top of the z-index ? At least just to check if it's there

Comment: I tried the suggested solution but it does not seem to work, I created a clean example where (area = spinnerScanning) See in this codepen with Hiro Marker https://codepen.io/mikenunes/pen/LeWJJZ
  What is the error and how to make it work? Thanks in advance

Comment: @MiguelNunes ill check it out at home but it looks like You didn't add the marker to the a-scene, like here: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/README.md#augmented-reality-for-the-web-in-less-than-10-lines-of-html

Comment: I created a version with a-marker and z-index but it also does not work!  What am I doing wrong here? https://codepen.io/mikenunes/pen/dJWbqm

Comment: Piotr Adam Milewski, can you help me?

Comment: @MiguelNunes here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXjbre , there were a few errors, first of all You need to attach the component, i've added it to the box, second of all there were a few syntax errors (like material=" ""), and You tried to grab by ID an element with a given class name. Anyway its working now

Comment: Thank you so much,  learned a lot with you.. A great teacher!

Comment: glad i could help, if you don't have any further questions feel free to mark the anwser :)